# Branching, Merging and Re-merging in tfs

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

I am new to TFS. I read some articles on branching and merging features in TFS.

I wanted to know for my scenario how the branching and merging features of TFS can be used.

I have a Development branch. There are 2 features branches also created based on Development branch. Some developers have checked-in their code in Feature 1 and Feature 2 branch. Now, Feature 1 branch is merged in Development branch and Feature 2 branch is yet to be merged in Development branch.

How will the Feature 2 branch get the code of Feature 1 branch.

> Will get latest version work for this?

Some of my friends suggested that first Feature 2 branch will need to get merged in Development branch and then the Development branch should be merged back to Feature 2 branch.

Its quite confusing for me as I want that once I have checked-in my Feature branch, it should always get latest code from the Development branch.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

After you merge Feature 1 to DEV you then have to merge DEV to feature 2 branch